# Unable to run thes scapy program gone through various solutions but nthing works

Tags: scapy

```
import scapy.all as scapy

def scan(ip):
    scapy.arping(ip)


scan("192.168.0.1/24")

error:ModuleNotFoundError: no module named as 'scapy'
```

Comment: Did you run `pip install scapy`?

Comment: I agree with @Filnor, most likely it is not installed:

can you run that for us:
'pip list'

and give us the output?